# python time.time() move forward/backward hours/mins/secs

Tags: python

What I want to achieve is easy:

time.time() is not quite readable. How to get the following:

e.g.

```
time.time() //say, it's May 15 2013 13:15:46
```

How to get the following given time.time() above:

May 15 2013 ***12***:15:46

May 15 2013 ***14***:15:46

May 15 2013 13:***14***:46

May 15 2013 13:***16***:46

I am looking for something like:

```
def back_an_hr(current_time):
    .....
def back_a_min(current_time):
    .....

back_an_hr(time.time()) # this brings time.time() back an hr
back_a_min(time.time()) # this brings time.time() back a min
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be better off with the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 15, 15, 30, 17, 908152)
>>> onehour = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
>>> oneminute = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
>>> now + onehour
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 15, 16, 30, 17, 908152)
>>> now + oneminute
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 15, 15, 31, 17, 908152)
>>> now.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
'May 15 2013 15:30:17'
>>> (now - onehour).strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
'May 15 2013 14:30:17'
```

Comment: Just in case if OP needs the Unix time, he can get it from the `datetime` like `time.mktime(dt.timetuple())`

Answer (score 0):

Python has a module called datetime and timedelta. With These modules you can define your own functions back_an_hr(current_time) and back_a_min(current_time)

The timedelta takes an offset and you can define the offset as being a day, month, year, hour minute or second.

Answer (score 0):

time.time() gives number of seconds as a float.

```
time.time() - (60 * 60 * 24) # 1 day
```